# No. of integer ordered pairs $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2012$

Tags: number-theory

[1] No. of integer ordered pairs $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2012$

[2] No. of integer ordered pairs $(x,y,z)$ in $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1980$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ for (1) one ::

$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2012 = 4\times 503$

means $x,y,z$ must be an even integer. So $x=2x^{'}$ and $y=2y^{'}$ and $z=2z^{'}$

where $x^{'},y^{'},z^{'}\in \mathbb{Z}$

So $4\cdot \left((x^{'})^2+(y^{'})^2+(z^{'})^2\right) = 4\times 503$

So $(x^{'})^2+(y^{'})^2+(z^{'})^2 = 503$

Now How can i solve after that

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: You have an error, $x,y,z$ need not all be even. It is clear $4$ divides $2012$ so that $4$ divides $x^2+y^2+z^2$. Since the only squares $\mod 4$ are $0$ and $1$. Either all of $x,y,z$ have to be divisible by $4$ or two of them do. So either they are all even or only one of them is.

Comment: There are NO ordered pairs $(x,y,z)$. There may be some ordered *triples* $(x,y,z)$, but no such ordered pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth knowing the following:

- If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is divisible by $4$.
- If $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ leaves a remainder $1$, when divided by $4$ or $8$.

Now note that since $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2012$, we can have the following two cases:

1. $2$ of them are odd and one is even. In this cases, $x^2+y^2+z^2$ will leave a remainder $2$ when divided by $4$, whereas $2012$ is exactly divisible by $4$. Hence, this case is not possible.
2. All of them are even. In which case, as you have rightly done, $x=2x_1$, $y=2y_1$ and $z=2z_1$. Hence, $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 = 503$. Now note that we have two possible options for $x_1$, $y_1$ and $z_1$. Either two of them are even and one is odd (or) all three are odd. If tw0 of them are even and one is odd, then $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2$ leaves a remainder $1$, when divided by $4$, whereas $503$ leaves a remainder $3$, when divided by $4$. Hence, the only possibility is all of $x_1,y_1$ and $z_1$ are odd. However, if all of them are odd, then $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2$ leaves a remainder $3$, when divided by $8$, whereas $503$ leaves a reminder $7$ when divided by $8$.

Hence, there is no integer solution for $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2012$.

Repeat the same argument for $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1980$.

Comment: in case of interest: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer/22655#22655

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Part [1]: ZERO.
$$ 503 \equiv 7 \pmod 8. $$
Also $n$ is the sum of three squares if and only if $4n$ is the sum of three squares.

Part [2]: ZERO.
$$ 495 \equiv 7 \pmod 8. $$